# Visual Studio 2008 Solution has wrong "Opened URL" path for Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have a project solution I am migrating from another computer, and the project opens the wrong "Opened URL".

When viewing the Properties for the Web Site, the following path is correct and working on the old computer.

file:///C:/Collection/Server Workspace/store.domain/Main/store.domain

When the same solution is transferred via TFS to my computer, the Opened URL path adds an additional "store.domain" at the end of the path:

file:///C:/Collection/store.domain/Main/store.domain/**store.domain**

Editing the path inside Visual Studio isn't an option, its greyed out and not editable. Editing the text of the solution file shows no duplicate "store.domain"s either.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, perhaps with IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in the web site from the old computer to have the correct URL stored in TFS Version Control. Then get latest version for that web site on your dev machine.

Comment: The URL is correct and all files checked in on the old computer. Basically, is there a way to edit the path in the new computer manually?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The solution file on the old computer only worked when inside the folder with all of the files. The same solution file on the new computer, needed to be in the parent directory.

So the fix was to move the solution up one directory, for whatever reason. This allowed the phantom /store.domain folder to line up correctly.